# Rasterizing arbitrary geometry to GeoTIFF in Python?

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, geometry

Say I have a list of points like so:

```
[([11.36119, 48.296505], 0.0001402984),
 ([11.883914, 48.215576], 7.610937e-05),
 ([11.599947, 48.125195], 0.000109944136),
 ([11.699542, 48.005215], 4.153407e-05),
 ([11.24905, 47.8968], 5.1380226e-05),
 ([11.540143, 48.313515], 0.00011384409),
 ([11.225697, 48.15368], 0.00012962254),
 ([11.720368, 48.13634], 8.023686e-05),
 ([11.205321, 48.21643], 9.852748e-05),
 ([11.599908, 47.93122], 6.480781e-05),
 ([11.700613, 48.199123], 7.999575e-05),
 ([11.580477, 48.3819], 7.9131554e-05),
 ([11.639637, 47.99963], 6.16816e-05),
 ([11.620302, 48.25634], 8.833698e-05),
 ([11.759764, 48.01076], 3.528253e-05),
 ([11.440642, 48.239445], 8.462306e-05),
 ([11.520233, 48.182346], 0.0001502913),
 ([11.659999, 48.130787], 9.65557e-05),
 ([11.839879, 47.953472], 5.870264e-05),
 ([11.66101, 48.32468], 0.000102694095)]
```

I would like to **create a GeoTIFF from Python** of a choropleth of these points (that is, the highest values (the last column) coloured red and the lowest values coloured blue).

An important note is that this data is not gridded - these are *arbitrary* points (in future I would like to do the same for arbitrary polygons). I have tried to do this with `georasters` with no luck, but it may be possible with `rasterio` or similar. In general it seems that many of these libraries are useful for consuming GeoTIFFs but not many have a lot of documentation about creating them.

Comment: You probably need to interpolate the data. You can use scipy for that and export as raster.

Comment: @BERA Would you be able to elaborate and add an answer? Thanks!